# I cannot get electron-wix-msi running

Tags: wix, windows-installer, electron

I had problems to get an electron project using webpack to get packed as an MSI installer. I came around *electron-wix-msi* package. It's a wrapper for the great WIX toolkit. The advantage is, that it is more Windows like.

However, the docs are unclear and not sufficient to get it immediately running. Finally I got it and want to share the steps here.

Answer (score 6):

I used TypeScript for development and got a working installation for all parts, including MSI.

> This is for Windows users only. The process describes the creation of an Windows-Installer (MSI).

1. Install Wix Toolkit as mentioned in docs
2. Add path to **candle.exe** and **light.exe**, which is "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin" to path variable. Check that if you enter "candle" at prompt the candle.exe executes.
3. Create installation file as *make-msi.ts* in folder *build* (just a suggestion, any path will do it):

```
import * as msi from 'electron-wix-msi';
import * as path from 'path';

// Step 1: Instantiate the MSICreator
const msiCreator = new msi.MSICreator({
    appDirectory: path.resolve('release/win-unpacked'), // result from electron-builder
    description: 'Some text',
    exe: 'MyExe',
    name: 'MyExe',
    manufacturer: 'Joerg Krause',
    version: '0.5.0',
    language: 1033,
    arch: 'x86',
    outputDirectory: path.resolve('release/msi/')
});

async function createMsi() {
    // Step 2: Create a .wxs template file
    await msiCreator.create();

    // Step 3: Compile the template to a .msi file
    await msiCreator.compile();
}
console.log('Invoke MSI Builder');
createMsi();
```

> *release/win-unpacked* is the output from *electron-builder*.

4. Add *tsconfig.json* with appropriate settings in same folder *build*:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "es5",
      "dom"
    ],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "outDir": "js",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types",
    ]
  }
}
```

5. Check both files in the folder *build*
6. Add `npm run` command like this to your *package.json*:

```
cd build && tsc && cd .. && node build/js/make-msi.js
```

My whole scripts block looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "tsc win.ts --outDir ./dist && cross-env NODE_ENV=dev && npm run prev",
    "build": "rimraf ./dist && webpack",
    "start": "rimraf ./dist && webpack && electron .",
    "prev": "electron .",
    "test": "jest",
    "msi": "cd build && tsc && cd .. && node build/js/make-msi.js",
    "pack": "npm run build && rimraf ./release && build --dir && npm run msi",
    "dist": "build"
  }
```

This compiles the TypeScript into ES and executes the script with `npm run msi`. After a while you have your MSI.

Also, I had much more success using *electron-builder* instead of *electron-packager*.

For those who want to get more, my setup is as this:

- I write my apps with HTML 5 API (no React/Angular or so). I can really recommend this for small and medium apps.
- I use TypeScript 3 for all coding stuff
- I use SASS for all CSS stuff
- Using webpack to compile, optimise and pack
- I use *electron-builder* to bundle
- I use the process described above to make a Windows package.

Comment: The path variable to the toolset is what I was missing - cheers

Answer (score 0):

Great tutorial. Your tsconfig.json lacks one line to get "tsc" work, otherwise you will get an error like `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'path'`:

```
"types": ["node"],
```